# How can I unit test sweetalert with onAfterClose

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test sweetalert with has onAfterClose.

I mock sweetalert spyOn(Swal,"fire") it will not call onAfterClose. What should I set spyOn?

example .ts

```
testFunction(value) {
if (!value) {
   Swal.fire({ type: 'success', title: 'Success', text: 'Success', onAfterClose: () => {
      // call function
      this.clearAll();
      ...
   }
}
```

example spec.ts

```
describe('test function', () => {
   it('should call clearAll when call testFunction and close sweetalert', () => {
      spyOn(Swal,"fire");
      component.testFunction(false);
      // Swal.close();
      // expect(component.clearAll).toHaveBeenCall();
})
})
```

I want to test 
expect(component.clearAll).toHaveBeenCalled();

Comment: Maybe provide your actual code ?

Comment: For your test, shouldn't you be spying on `clearAll` since SweetAlert is a third party lib. Once you call `fire` on `Swal`, you can then expect `clearAll` to have been called. You can always check `fixture.whenStable()` before checking if `clearAll` was called.

Comment: I have already call `fixture.whenStable().then(()=>{console.log("test")})` but no log shows on console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spies don't return any value or don't run anything by default, so make it return/run something that matches the signature of the function. You will need to trigger the callback yourself. Try this :

```
spyOn(Swal,"fire").and.callFake(args => { args.onAfterClose(); });
component.testFunction(false);
expect(component.clearAll).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to calSwal.clickConfirm() to click on Confirm button programmatically and after that put your expect in setTimeout.

```
deleteLocalItems(itemId) {
    Swal({
      titleText: 'Are you sure to delete item?',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
      cancelButtonText: 'No',
      showCancelButton: true
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value !== undefined && result.value) {
        const item = this.items.find(i => i.id === itemId);
        this.items.splice(this.items.indexOf(item), 1);
      }
    });
  }
```

can be test as

```
it('should delete item on confirmation', (done) => {
    component.items = [
      { id: '1001', name: 'Product 1'},
      { id: '1002', name: 'Product 2'},
      { id: '1003', name: 'Product 3'},
      { id: '1004', name: 'Product 4'}];

    component.deleteLocalItems('1003');
    expect(Swal.isVisible()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(Swal.getTitle().textContent).toEqual('Are you sure to delete item?');
    Swal.clickConfirm();
    setTimeout(() => {
      expect(component.items.length).toEqual(3);
      done();
    });
  });
```

Comment: You can use the fakeasync

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fakeasync with this

```
it('should call clearAll when call testFunction and close sweetalert', fakeAsync(() => {
  // Arrange
  component.items = [
    { id: '100', name: 'Product 1' },
    { id: '100', name: 'Product 2' },
  ];

  // Act
  component.deleteLocalItems('100');

  // Assert
  expect(Swal.isVisible()).toBeTruthy();
  expect(Swal.getTitle().textContent).toEqual('your message');
  Swal.clickConfirm();
  flush();
  expect(component.items.length).toEqual(1);
}));
```